# Correlation between variables - which kind of regression to choose?

Tags: correlation

I am asking for your advice,
I have two independent variables with correlation of 0.5. The variables are as follows:
(1) Family ownership, which refers to the family % in ownership
(2) Founder, dummy variable with 1/0 if the manager is the founder

The correlation is 0.5 as in some firms this is the same person. If I want to check the "PURE" impact of each variable on the dependent variable, what you suggest me to do? (PURE means, for example, the real impact of being founder w/o the ownership too).
My first idea (that also checked) was to run the regression of founder impact only between similar ownership groups, but in this way I am loosing a lot of data that is not used and might help.

Can you please give any clue how to handle with it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try the LASSO regression

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1$ be ownership percent, $x_2$ be founder dummy$.

The correlation between $x_1$ and $x_2$ being 0.5 is not big issue. You need to fit a model with $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_1x_2$ (interaction of $x_1$ and $x_2$) as covariates. If $x_1x_2$ is important (significant) in the model, "PURE" impact does not exist. It means the effect of ownership percent depends on founder or not founder; the effect of founder depends on the percent of ownership.

If  $x_1x_2$ is not important (significant), fit a model with $x_1$ and $x_2$ only. Then you get the effect of $x_1$ and $x_2$ simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks and you are right, I found the effect of founder depends on ownership is positive